# Marking correct answer when multiple answers are used

Tags: discussion, support, accepted-answer

On some Stack Exchange sites it is unclear to me which answer to accept as correct. For example, sites such as lifehacks, scifi and personal productivity, give theories and tools, several which (or a combination) may be right. In this example [I asked how to tell if a surface is level](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9470/how-to-tell-if-surface-is-level) however I used solutions from multiple answers at some point in time.

Which answer, if any, should be marked as correct? Is there pressure to mark any answer as correct? I guess I always assumed the correct answer is the one actually used. IMO there shouldn't be pressure on accepting an answer, however there often is from those who posted the answer as they would get more points for an accepted answer.

Comment: Don't let people pressure you into accepting. If they do, flag it as "not constructive".

Answer (score 1):

Accepting an answer is not bounded and not final. You can unaccept an answer later if you found some new answer which is the "best answer" in your opinion. If someone is pressurizing you in comments, you can flag the comment.

From the help center:

> The first thing you should do after reading someone's answer to your
>   question is vote on the answer, like any other user (with sufficient
>   reputation) does. Vote up answers that are helpful and
>   well-researched, and vote down answers that are not. Other users will
>   also vote on answers to your question.
>
> As the author of the question, you have an additional option:
>   accepting an answer that you believe is the best solution to your
>   problem.
>
> Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept
>   the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that
>   answers your question well.
>
> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final
>   statement indicating that the question has now been answered
>   perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that
>   worked for him or her personally. Not every user comes back to accept
>   an answer, and of those who do, they might not change the accepted
>   answer even if a newer, better answer comes along later.

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers